# How can I change a button text onClick?

Tags: java, android, onclick, counter

I'm new to Android and in my class we have to make a program where every time a button is pressed the count increases and this number is shown inside the button. For example, the button starts at 0 and I click the button and it changes the text from 0 to 1, than click again it goes from 1 to 2 and so on but number changes in the button. Is it possible to do something like this without using TextView?

This is what I have on my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="countUp"
        android:text="0"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="72dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="61dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this is what I have on my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.tapgrid;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button showValue;
    int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showValue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    public void countUp (Button view) {
        counter++;
        showValue.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
    }

}
```

Comment: App is crashing?

Comment: Button inherits from TextView, so you can simply use setText() on it.

Answer (score 1):

EditText accepts only Strings values since the counter variable is an integer so the app crashes, it is better to cast it to string then set it to edittext

```
showValue.setText(String.valueOf(counter));
```

Comment: Although this may be a valid answer, it is good to provide some explanation.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I have updated my answer with explaination.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the onClick Listener on the button which listens to click events

```
findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(clickListener);
...

private View.OnClickListener clickListener = v -> {
    int count = Integer.parseInt(((Button) v).getText().toString());
    ((Button) v).setText(String.valueOf(++count));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String str = (String) button.getText();
                int i = Integer.parseInt(str);
                button.setText(String.valueOf(++i));

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.